# How to generate a multidimensional array with unknown amount of dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to define an array with n dimensions. So it should be a matrix with n dimensions. Is it possible in java to define such a variable?
For example I can use

```
method(int[]...)
```

to give multiple arrays to a method, but can I do something like

```
int[]... variable;
```

to generate an n-dimensional array?

Comment: you can't do it. use `ArrayList` instead

Comment: you can't do it. use MatLab instead

Comment: You can represent every `n`-dimensional array as a 1-dimensional array. You simply have to transform the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to create an dynamic-dimensional array in java. However, you can certainly accomplish this kind of task using nested objects!